# Switch panels and add according classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I got these panels and they work nice, but if I click two times on the same navigation item (Standard, Plus), the class disappears… Also, for example if I click on "Free" **panel**, and afterwards on "Standard" **button** it does not switch it… Any ideas what is wrong here..? Here's a pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Wyzgmj

```
$(".pricing-select__item--ent").on('click', function() {

        $(".pricing-panel").removeClass("pricing-panel--selected");

        if($(".pricing-select__item--tms").hasClass("pricing-select__item--selected--color")) {
            $(".pricing-select__item--tms").removeClass("pricing-select__item--selected--color");
            $(this).addClass("pricing-select__item--selected--color");

            $(".pricing-panel--ent").addClass("pricing-panel--selected");
        }
    });

    $(".pricing-select__item--tms").on('click', function() {

        $(".pricing-panel").removeClass("pricing-panel--selected");

        if($(".pricing-select__item--ent").hasClass("pricing-select__item--selected--color")) {
            $(".pricing-select__item--ent").removeClass("pricing-select__item--selected--color");
            $(this).addClass("pricing-select__item--selected--color");

            $(".pricing-panel--tms").addClass("pricing-panel--selected");
        }
    });

    $(".pricing-panel").click(function() {
        $(".pricing-panel").removeClass("pricing-panel--selected");
        $(this).addClass("pricing-panel--selected");

        if($(this).hasClass("pricing-panel--tms")) {
            $(".pricing-select__item--ent").removeClass("pricing-select__item--selected--color");
            $(".pricing-select__item--tms").addClass("pricing-select__item--selected--color");
        }

        if($(this).hasClass("pricing-panel--ent")) {
            $(".pricing-select__item--tms").removeClass("pricing-select__item--selected--color");
            $(".pricing-select__item--ent").addClass("pricing-select__item--selected--color");
        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't see any issue in codepen

Comment: Me neither.....

Comment: There are a lot of logic issues in your code, I have created a [pen](https://codepen.io/zinduyaar/pen/wXmYrr) for your 1st issue, for 2nd issue you need to create 3rd button ("Free") and bind one more click event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Add this Code at end of your .pricing-select__item--ent click function

```
$(".pricing-panel--ent").addClass("pricing-panel--selected");
```

Just Add this Code at end of your .pricing-select__item--tms click function

```
$(".pricing-panel--tms").addClass("pricing-panel--selected");
```

for example:

```
 $(".pricing-select__item--ent").on('click', function() {

    $(".pricing-panel").removeClass("pricing-panel--selected");

    if($(".pricing-select__item--tms").hasClass("pricing-select__item--selected--color")) {
        $(".pricing-select__item--tms").removeClass("pricing-select__item--selected--color");
        $(this).addClass("pricing-select__item--selected--color");

        $(".pricing-panel--ent").addClass("pricing-panel--selected");
    }
    $(".pricing-panel--ent").addClass("pricing-panel--selected"); //here
});

$(".pricing-select__item--tms").on('click', function() {

    $(".pricing-panel").removeClass("pricing-panel--selected");

    if($(".pricing-select__item--ent").hasClass("pricing-select__item--selected--color")) {
        $(".pricing-select__item--ent").removeClass("pricing-select__item--selected--color");
        $(this).addClass("pricing-select__item--selected--color");

        $(".pricing-panel--tms").addClass("pricing-panel--selected");
    }
    $(".pricing-panel--tms").addClass("pricing-panel--selected"); //here
});
```